# MiKTeX 2.9 (for x86), Win 7 (x64): biber not running as if not installed

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I installed biber through MiKTeX's package manager but when trying to compile my references, nothing happens, as if biber was not installed when, in fact, its .exe is present under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` and this path is included in the system variables. Bibtex works just fine.

I tried to delete the `par-4e69636f6c6173` folder under `C:\Users\Nicolas\AppData\Local\Temp` created each time I try to run biber through the command prompt, but to no avail. Typing `biber test` systematically creates 4 files in my `Temp` folder: `biber.exe`, `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll` and `perl516.dll`.

I also tried to run "Refresh FNDB" in MiKTeX settings.

Any insights ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{alamargot2001,
title = {What makes a skilled writer? {W}orking memory and audience awareness during text composition},
volume = {21},
shorttitle = {What makes a skilled writer?},
number = {5},
urldate = {2013-03-02},
journal = {Learning and Individual Differences},
author = {Alamargot, Denis and Caporossi, Gilles and Chesnet, David and Ros, Christine},
year = {2001},
keywords = {Audience awareness, Expertise, Eye Movements, Individual differences, Online     measures, Procedural text, Written production},
pages = {505--516},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{alamargot2001}\ldots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Commands executed:

`xelatex test` produces test.log/aux/bcf/pdf, refs.bib and test.run.xml.

`biber test` or `biber test.bcf` produces nothing:
[image: biber command]

Comment: What happens if you type in `biber --version` at the command line? What happens if you try to compile a document via the command line (`pdlfatex test` `biber test` `pdlfatex test` `pdlfatex test`)?

Comment: @moewe: biber --version produces nothing. bibtex --version works (`MiKTeX-BibTeX 2.9 4360 (0.99d)`). PDFLaTeX works fine too. Changing Bib(la)tex's defautlt field in Texmaker (`bibtex %`) to `"C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/biber.exe" %` does not work either.

Comment: If your tex file produce file with extension `myfile.bcf`, try type in your command line `biber myfile.bcf`. Maybe you can see that in you project folder is `myfile.bbl` which has size 0B. This is important. In command line, you can se warning:`INFO - This is Biber 1.8`
`INFO - Logfile is 'myfile.blg'
INFO - Reading 'myfile.bcf'`
**WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.4, expected version 2.5** and this problem. Is that so?

Comment: Could you add listing from your command line into your question? Especially from command biber myfile.bbl? Please see http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=22548

Comment: @jafan there is no `test.bbl` file, only `test.aux` and `test.bcf`. I added more informations into my question.

Comment: This looks like a corrupt biber.exe if it says absolutely nothing. What happens if you download it from SF and replace the biber.exe in your MikTeX tree?

Comment: @PLK download from `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber/binaries/Windows` or `http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/?source=directory` did not change anything.

Comment: I just tried this download on a win7 64-bit machine and it was fine. I suspect that you might have a broken PAR directory. Try and search for any folder called "par-*" on the machine and delete it.

Comment: I just solved my issue. I think it was related to `C:\Users\Nicolas\AppData\Local\Temp` directory and subdirectories. I lowered the User Account Control setting to the minimum and now it works. I had another issue with Foxit Reader Updater.exe not being able to run and this error message `windows cannot access the specified device...` and now it's solved too, probably for the same reason has this .exe was also in `Temp` directory.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hardly reproduce-able (very localised) problem solved by a change not relating to LaTeX at all.