# Biber fails to run due to lack of administrator permissions?

Tags: miktex, biber

I am on a university computer (Windows 8.1, 64-bit) where MikTeX 2.9 is installed in multiuser mode via Software Center, and I am having trouble getting `biber` to run (The MikTeX-installation seems to be working fine except for this.). Trying to run `biber` on the command line outputs nothing, produces no `bbl`- or `blg`-file and only returns to the prompt. However, it does produce the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-somenumbers` with some files in it.

Others have had similar problems with `biber` on Windows ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159606/major-problem-with-biblatex-biber) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145270/miktex-2-9-for-x86-win-7-x64-biber-not-running-as-if-not-installed)) and [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302945/executing-binary-does-not-work-and-does-not-return-anything-although-expected), and the problem seems to be related to permissions required by `biber`, in particular in relation to the Temp-folder mentioned above, but I fail to understand exactly what those permissions are since my user already has write-permissions to the Temp-folder.

As was suggested in the first link above, `biber` runs fine if my IT-manager opens a command line as an administrator. However, this is not an option for me or others on a managed computer. So how can `biber` be given the necessary permissions so that a user without administrator rights can run it, both from the command line or from within an IDE such as TeXnicCenter?

Comment: Does the files in the temp/par-folder complete? E.g. are there the .dll's ? If not something perhaps blocks biber to unpack everything. You could then try to set the PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP variable to some other folder. see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70

Comment: There were four .dll's and biber.exe in the par-folder, but setting the PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP variable to a new folder under the Documents folder seems to have solved this frustrating problem. Thank you! In searching for how to set PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP, I came across your answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289479/biber-does-not-start) to essentially the same problem, except that there was an error message in that case.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems everything is not well quite yet... `biber`still won't run from within TeXnicCenter? My settings are taken from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154794#154794). And if I exit the command prompt, the PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP variable is discarded? How can I set it permanently?

Comment: Search in windows for "environment variables", it should point you to the place where the user can store them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Great, now everything works. Thanks! I don't know if my question should be marked as a duplicate or if it should be answered...?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. I have taken the liberty to make the link in the answer clickable, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first run biber needs to unpack a lot of files in a temporary folder. Sometimes some security setting can block the unpacking -- completely or only some files.

You then can try to set the `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` environment variable to point to some other folder where you have free write access.

See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70